# Use 'if' to find maximum and minimum

Tags: c, if-statement

I write these codes to find the maximum and minimum in five different integers.

I know this is not the best approach. It could find the maximum, but the value of 'min' is always equal to 'a', which was assigned at the beginning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Enter five numbers and find the maximum and minimum.
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, max = a, min = a;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
    if (b > max) {
        max = b;
    }
    if (c > max) {
        max = c;
    }
    if (d > max) {
        max = d;
    }
    if (e > max) {
        max = e;
    }
    if (b < min) {
        min = b;
    }
    if (c < min) {
        min = c;
    }
    if (d < min) {
        min = d;
    }
    if (e < min) {
        min = e;
    }
    printf("Maximum: %d\nMinimum: %d", max, min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `min = INT_MAX` and `max = INT_MIN`. (defined in file "limits.h").

Comment: @barakmanos No, this has no sense. The correct approach is to initialize `min` or `max` to a value of `a`, `b`, etc.

Comment: @Stargateur: Why does this make no sense?

Comment: off topic- Use an array to take in the inputs and iterate over the array to find min and max values. Your code will be simpler.

Comment: @barakmanos, @Stargateur: Both approaches work but the `limits.h` constants allow an algorithm to work with empty sequences.

Comment: @barakmanos It's hard to explain but they are no reason to not use a value already present in the set that you want to test. This has more sense with an array but the OP use 5 variable. But with your solution you need to test `a` too and some people could say if your final value is `INT_MAX` an error has happen. @Potatoswatter say exactly what I fear, a min and a max has no sense on empty sequences. And `INT_MAX` could be a legit value. So how the user see the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `max` and `min` are set to `1` at the beginning but after the input, the value of `a` changes but max and min remain `1`.

You can solve this by initializing the `max` and `min` after the `scanf` statement or you could just initialize `max` and `min` to `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` defined in `limits.h` as pointed out by [Barak Manos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1382251/barak-manos).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//Enter five numbers and find the maximum and minimum.
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d,e;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
    int max = a, min = a;
    ....
    ....
}
```

Also, a simple version would be store all the input numbers in an array and call `min` and `max` on that array.

Comment: A bit of credit to the original comment (stating the exact same thing) wouldn't hurt anyone...

Comment: But when I run the original code and enter 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, it dose print out '**Maximum: 66 Minimum: 1**' (only `max` has been changed), that really confused me.

Answer (score 4):

You initialize `max` and `min` with the value of `a` **before** you ask for user input. Updating `a` doesn't update `min` and `max`.

The expression `max = a` copies the value of `a` in to `max`. It doesn't set max to track `a`.

Since you omitted `a` from all the calculations, the minimum and maximum will not take it into account.

Answer (score 3):

You can also input the values into an array. If you use this method, you can set `max` and `min` to `array[0]`, and iterate from `i=1` to `i=n` and compare `array[i]` with the `max` and `min` values. if a new `max` or `min` value is found, set them to `array[i]`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5

int main(void) {
    int array[SIZE], min, max;

    printf("Enter %d numbers:\n", SIZE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid number entered\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    max = min = array[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        } else if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Maximum: %d\nMinimum: %d\n", max, min);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you inizialize `min` and `max` before affect `a`.

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int e;
// you should check the return of function
if (scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e) != 5) { 
  return 1;
}
int max = a;
int min = a;
```

By the way, in your case the correct prototype of the main is `int main(void);`

Answer (score 2):

Restructure your code this way :

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
    int min = a, max = a;
    // rest of your code here;
}
```

Also, do not see the use of initializing a,b,c,d and e with different values when you are going to scan those inputs from standard input.

This code will not work in situations when user has input all 0s as input. Then your minimum calculation will be incorrect.

So it is best to initialize min with `INT_MAX` and max with `INT_MIN`

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can implement the following through this code.
If you assign values of max and min before scanning a's value there could be a problem.

For ex: I enter 5 numbers 3,4,5,6,7 as follows I will get 1 as value for min from your code.So this problem can be removed simply by defining max and min after getting user input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Enter five numbers and find the maximum and minimum.
int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, d, e, min, max;

    if (scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e) != 5)
        return 1;

    min = max = a;
    if (b > max) {
        max = b;
    }
    if (c > max) {
        max = c;
    }
    if (d > max) {
        max = d;
    }
    if (e > max) {
        max = e;
    }
    if (min > b) {
        min = b;
    }
    if (min > c) {
        min = c;
    }
    if (min > d) {
        min = d;
    }
    if (min > e) {
        min = e;
    }
    printf("Maximum: %d\nMinimum: %d", max, min);
    return 0;
}
```

Cheers !

Comment: I didnt get you sir.

Comment: Got it sir.Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

As others have diagnosed:

- `min` and `max` are set to `1` before the value of `a` is read from the user. The fix is to initialize `min` and `max` **after** reading the values.
- the initialization of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` is useless.
- the return value of `scanf()` should be tested to avoid undefined behavior.
- the prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`.
- the last `printf` should output a final newline to ensure proper flushing on all platforms.

Here is a different approach with a single loop. It uses a classic trick to make all comparisons generic: `min` is initialized to the largest possible `int` value and `max` to the smallest:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5

int main(void) {
    int array[SIZE], min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;

    printf("Enter %d numbers:\n", SIZE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid number entered\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (max < array[i]) {
            max = array[i];
        }
        if (min > array[i]) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum: %d\nMinimum: %d\n", max, min);
    return 0;
}
```